# UIWebView inside of UISplitView not sizing correctly

Tags: ios, ipad, cocoa-touch

I have a Split View controller interface in which the master controller is always visible, even in portrait orientation.  One of the detail views is a UIViewController that contains a UIWebView and it implements UIWebViewDelegate.

This UIViewController (and the nested web view) have the dimensions 450 x 960 set in Interface Builder.  For some reason, when the view loads, however, the web page is retrieved with the dimensions 768 x 1024 (I have verified this by doing a javascript alert of the screen.height and screen.width).  This has the unhappy effect of causing the loaded webpage to display such that most of it "off stage" to the right and rendering any responsive design useless.  Even more strangely, if log the frame and bounds of both the view and webview in webViewDidFinishLoad, they both indicate the proper dimensions of 450 x 960.

Here is the contents of ViewDidLoad

```
self.loginWebView.delegate = self;
[loginWebView setScalesPageToFit:YES];
[loginWebView loadRequest:[NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://www.smashingmagazine.com/"]]];
```

It is almost as if the viewcontroller and/or webview are being resized to take up the entire screen, regardless of the fact that the master view controller is always displayed.  What am I missing here?